# environment variables in .bashrc not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using a Rails app with Devise (for authentication) and the omniauth gem on a remote server. When I used to deploy to Heroku, I could set environment variables in the terminal, but that's not offered on the remote server I'm using. I therefore added the following to the bottom of `.bashrc`

```
export TWITTER_KEY="LxAuQ1Chmas;dlfkjdsal;fjds" TWITTER_SECRET="CC2XpLOeMJbvYphlafsdlkfjdsalkfj"
```

hoping that would set the environment variables configured in the Devise.rb file

```
 config.omniauth :twitter, ENV["TWITTER_KEY"], ENV["TWITTER_SECRET"]
```

However, when I try to sign in with Twitter, I'm getting this

```
OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
  omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:29:in `request_phase'
  omniauth-twitter (1.0.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:63:in `request_phase'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:214:in `request_call'
```

so I'm assuming the environment variables aren't be read correctly.  Can you explain another way I might set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest managing environment variables with the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem.

Put environment variables in the yaml configuration file and they will be available in `ENV`.

It also provides a helpful rake task to set the variables on Heroku.

Comment: I tried figaro earlier on my local machine and couldn't get it to work. I thought maybe it wasn't ready for Rails 4 yet.

Comment: @Leahcim Which version of figaro did you tried? Versions after 0.6.0 should support Rails 4. I would suggest trying the latest version (0.7.0).

Comment: I installed the latest figaro yesterday but it didn't work. If I hardcode the api information in, the site works properly, so I'm certain the error's coming from how I'm setting environment variables, whether I use figaro or bashprofile.  Figaro's dead simple, I set environment variables following the example in application.yml like this without success `TWITTER_KEY: "LxAuQ1ChmG5dfljafkjdsalkfjg" 
TWITTER_SECRET: "CC2XpLOeMJbvYphfCyTQdlIsfljadsfkljadslkfjs"`

Comment: @Leahcim Does `ENV['TWITTER_KEY']` in Rails console print out the Twitter key you set?

Comment: I think the problem was that after I set the env variables on the remote server i didn't restart it.

Comment: that is, the problem was that after installing figaro i didn't restart the server